# Can't delete an element in jQuery after it creation

Tags: jquery, element

I create some element by jQuery. Those elements are draggable and resizable. I can delete initial element (Accordeon, Flip and Swipe). My problem is when I want to create Image object (click Image Box on top bar). I could not delete it. Could you please help me? Thanks.

Here's my jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mV75R/

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<style>
body { margin:0px; padding:0px; border:0px; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }

#PageOptions { width:240px; height:100%; border-right:1px solid #E5E5E5; margin:0px; padding:5px; background:#FFF8E7; position:absolute; }

#PageContainer { width:986px; height:676px; border:3px solid #CCC; margin:10px 10px 10px 265px; background:#F1F1F1; position:absolute; }
#AdContainer { width:460px; height:670px; border:1px dashed #666; margin:0px; position:absolute; background:#FFF; }
.ui-widget-content { width:150px; height:150px; z-index:0; }
.handle { cursor: move; background-color:#CCC; padding:0px; margin:0px; }
.ui-resizable-helper { border: 1px dotted #900; }

#ObjList {width:100%; height:80px; border-bottom:1px solid #E5E5E5; display:block; background:#F1F1F1; }
ul, li { margin:0px; padding:0px; list-style-image:none; }
li { width:50px; height:50px; border:1px solid #CCC; display:inline-block; background:#F0E8BB; margin:5px; padding:5px; overflow:hidden; font-size:12px;  border-radius: 10px; }
</style>
<script>
$(function() {

    var draggableOptions = {
        containment: "#AdContainer",
        scroll: false,
        // grid: [5, 5],
        handle: ".handle",
        snap: true,
        stack: "div",
        drag: function(event, ui) {
            var objId = $(this).attr("id");
            var objPos = $(this).position();
            $("#objName").text("Comportement: " + objId);
            $("#objTopPos").text("Marge à gauche:  " + objPos.left + "px");
            $("#objLeftPos").text("Marge en haut: " + objPos.top + "px");
        }
    };

    var resizableOptions = {
            animate: true,
            containment: "#AdContainer",
            resize: function(event, ui) {
                var objWidth = ui.size.width;
                var objHeight = ui.size.height;
                $("#objWidthSize").text("Largeur: " + objWidth + "px");
                $("#objHeightSize").text("Hauteur: " + objHeight + "px");
            },
            minHeight: 100,
            minWidth: 100,
    };

    $("#adSize").text("Taille de la publicité: " + $("#AdContainer").width() + "x" + $("#AdContainer").height());

    $(".ui-widget-content").draggable(draggableOptions).resizable(resizableOptions);

    // Obj creation
    $(".createObjImage").click(function () {
        var newObjImage = $('<div id="Image" class="ui-widget-content"><p class="handle"><span class="deleteObj">[x]</span> Image</p></div>').draggable(draggableOptions).resizable(resizableOptions);
        $("#AdContainer").append(newObjImage);
    })

    $(".deleteObj").click(function () {
        $(this).parents('.ui-widget-content').remove();
    })

});
</script>
</head>

<body> 
    <div id="ObjList">
        <ul>
            <li class="createObjImage">Image</li>
            <li class="createObjAccordeon">Accordeon</li>
            <li class="createObjSwipe">Swipe</li>
            <li class="createObjVideo">Video</li>
            <li class="createObjFlip">Flip</li>
            <li class="createObjSlider">Slider</li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="PageOptions">
        <span id="adSize"></span><br />
        ----------<br />
        <span id="objName"></span><br />
        <span id="objTopPos"></span><br />
        <span id="objLeftPos"></span><br />
        <span id="objWidthSize"></span><br />
        <span id="objHeightSize"></span>
    </div>

    <div id="PageContainer">
        <div id="AdContainer">
            <div id="Accordeon" class="ui-widget-content">
                <p class="handle"><span class="deleteObj">[x]</span> Accordeon</p>
            </div>
            <div id="Flip" class="ui-widget-content">
                <p class="handle"><span class="deleteObj">[x]</span> Flip</p>
            </div>
            <div id="Swipe" class="ui-widget-content">
                <p class="handle"><span class="deleteObj">[x]</span> Swipe</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The .click() creates a click-eventhandler for the matched elements, it does not assign the handler to future objects that may match. http://api.jquery.com/on/ you can use 'delegated' events to circumvent this, or attach the click event handler as you create the new objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
$(".deleteObj").click(function () {
        $(this).parents('.ui-widget-content').remove();
    })
```

there should be:

```
 $("#AdContainer").on('click', '.deleteObj', function () {
        $(this).parents('.ui-widget-content').remove();
    })
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mV75R/1/

`.click` will attach event to existing elements only. And once you add new element which should have that handler, you should attach event handler to new element explicitly. Or you can use [`.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) like above ([`.live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) in older versions of jQuery). It will work for newly created elements also.

Another option is to add click event handler once you create new Image element:

```
$(".createObjImage").click(function () {
        var newObjImage = $('<div id="Image" class="ui-widget-content"><p class="handle"><span class="deleteObj">[x]</span> Image</p></div>').draggable(draggableOptions).resizable(resizableOptions);
        $("#AdContainer").append(newObjImage);
        $('.deleteObj', newObjImage).click(function () {
              $(this).parents('.ui-widget-content').remove();
        });
    })
```

(of course, remove object code could be moved into separate function, instead of copy/paste)
Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mV75R/2/